# Kivy: dismiss() doesn't work on my ModalView widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a `ModalView` widget and trying to close it by pressing a button on it. The callback of the button press goes to method that suppose to close it.

This is main.kv:

```
<MainFrame>:
    id: main_frame
    ScreenMaster:
        id: screen_master
        StartScreen:
            id: start_screen
            SettingsPopup:
                id: settings_popup
        GameScreen:
            id: game_screen
            GameOverPopup:
                id: gameover_popup
```

And gameoverpopup.kv:

```
<GameOverPopup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    size_hint: .7, .4
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:
            id: close_button
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .05}
            size_hint: .8, .2
            text: 'PLAY AGAIN'
            on_press: root.done()
        Label:
            pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .8}
            size_hint: .6, .15
            font_size: 32
            text: 'YOU WON'
```

And main.py:

```
# kivy includes
Builder.load_file('startscreen.kv')
Builder.load_file('gamescreen.kv')
Builder.load_file('settingspopup.kv')
Builder.load_file('gameoverpopup.kv')

class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenMaster(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SettingsPopup(ModalView):
    pass

class GameOverPopup(ModalView):
    def done(self):
        self.dismiss()

class MainFrame(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Pressing `Play again` button calls `done()` method, but the `ModalView` widget doesn't dismiss. How can I solve this problem and make it disappear?

Answer (score 1):

`ModalView` or anything that inherits from it (`Popup`) aren't meant to be added as a child to anywhere. By default the `ModalView` is attached to a `Window` directly as it's mentioned in the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.modalview.html#kivy.uix.modalview.ModalView.open) when you call its `open()` method.

When you add it as a child somewhere, you'll automatically make it visible, which is ***bad*** because you misuse the purpose of that widget.

Instead of that you should just make it as a class/rule somewhere and ***call*** `open()` method when you need it to show. When you need to dismiss it manually, then you'll need to attach some method to `on_open` to store your instance of the `ModalView` class somewhere and call `dismiss()` through that instance or put a button somewhere on `ModalView`.

By your answer you only monkeypatch your mistake of misusing the widget. :)

There are two ways how to open a `ModalView`(or `Popup`):

**python:**

```
SettingsPopup().open()
```

**kv:**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
Factory.SettingsPopup().open()
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It causes a 'weakly-referenced object no longer exists' error. But the thing is - I need this reference.
What I am trying to say: on those SettingsPopup and GameOverPopup I have a buttons, which have a callbacks to their respective classes, but without this reference I cannot access any method of GameScreen or StartScreen via ids.
For example on GameOverPopup I have a button 'play again', which calls gamescreen.game_restart(), which I cannot call if I dont have this reference...

Comment: @Roman then store it somewhere instead of adding it as a child somewhere :)

Comment: @Roman You can use `__init__()` method of the `Popup` to do e.g. this: `App.get_running_app().my_popup = self` and then in kv do `app.my_popup`. Also, it might be a good idea to do `App.get_running_app().my_popup = None` in `on_dismiss` event. :)

Comment: Actually I've found another way :)
From here: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html
Referencing Widgets section, using __self__ in reference id.

Answer (score 0):

Have found a solution myself:

```
<MainFrame>:
    id: main_frame
    ScreenMaster:
        id: screen_master
        StartScreen:
            id: start_screen
            SettingsPopup:
                id: settings_popup
                on_parent: if self.parent == start_screen: start_screen.remove_widget(self)
        GameScreen:
            id: game_screen
            GameOverPopup:
                id: gameover_popup
                on_parent: if self.parent == game_screen: game_screen.remove_widget(self)
```

So we instantiate those popups and close them right away. Now we can open them back up anytime we want.